# QML Change ScrollBar Handle Color

Tags: qml

I want to change the scrollbar handle color, and follow the Qt doc

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquickcontrols2-customize.html#customizing-scrollbar

here is my code.

```
  ScrollView {
        id: view
        anchors.top: parent.top
        anchors.left: parent.left
        contentHeight: 300
        contentWidth: view.width
        width: 200
        height: 200
        focus: true
        ScrollBar.horizontal.policy: ScrollBar.AlwaysOff

        Label {
            text: "ABC"
            font.pixelSize: 224
        }

        background: Rectangle{
            color:"pink"
        }

        ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
            parent: view
            id: control
            active: true
            contentItem: Rectangle {
                implicitWidth: 6
                implicitHeight: 100
                radius: width / 2
                color: control.pressed ? "#81e889" : "#c2f4c6"
            }
        }
    }
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EiSid.png)

this result the handle will fill with scrollbar.

how to changed handle color and do not fill scrollbar?

---

here is update.
Try to setting implicitHeight to view.contentHeight

```
           ScrollBar.vertical: ScrollBar {
               parent: view
               id: control
               active: true
               contentItem: Rectangle {
                   implicitWidth: 6
                   implicitHeight: view.contentHeight
                   radius: width / 2
                   color: control.pressed ? "#81e889" : "#c2f4c6"
               }
           }
```

[here is result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SgZPN.png)

It is have same problem，it's change the whole ScrollBar, not handle.

Comment: I guess that setting `implicitHeight` to 100 will fit 1/3 of the `ScrollView` content. Maybe you should set some relative height, I mean the height according to the `contentHeight`?

Comment: @folibis thanks your reply, I update my post, I think the problem it's not implicitHeight, contentItem look like the whole scrollbar not handle.